# how to go to the particular frame depending upon check box value in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to create a question paper in as3,Flash.First I have created index page.
This index page contain all chapter names. I am using checkbox for these chapters.

If chapter 1 is selected it will go on frame3. Chapter 1 is having 10 questions. Each question is on different frame. 
If chapter 2 is selected it will go on frame14. Again Chapter 2 is having 10 questions. Each question is on different frame.

But if two chapters are selected using checkbox, I want to go to the frame 3. By clicking on Next button it will go till last question of chapter1. i.e. Question 10 on frame 13.
And after that it should go to the first frame of chapter 2. i.e. frame14.

And there are 10 chapters in index page. User can select any combination of chapters.

Comment: Show the code you have so far.

Comment: @MattCain This is my code:                                                         
    <pre><code>'gobtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fun2);
    gobtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fun2);
    function fun2(evt:Event):void
    {
     
     if(chap1.selected==true)
      gotoAndStop(3);
     if(chap2.selected==true)
      gotoAndStop(4);
      
    }
    
    backbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fun3);
    function fun3(evt1:Event):void
    {
     gotoAndStop(1);
    }

Comment: Check if you have access to `chap1` and `chap2` from `fun2` by tracing both objects. Also, if you swap your "if"s, you will end with `chap1` checkbox superseding `chap2`.

Answer (score 0):

You said your code is:

```
gobtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fun2); 
function fun2(evt:Event):void { 
    if(chap1.selected==true) gotoAndStop(3); 
    if(chap2.selected==true) gotoAndStop(14); 
} 
backbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fun3); 
function fun3(evt1:Event):void { gotoAndStop(1); }
```

In order to make your checkboxes work like you want (so if `chap1` is selected, you go to frame 3, regardless of whether `chap2` is selected, add an `else` after your first `if`.

```
gobtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fun2); 
function fun2(evt:Event):void { 
    if(chap1.selected==true) gotoAndStop(3); 
    else // this is what's added
    if(chap2.selected==true) gotoAndStop(14); 
} 
backbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fun3); 
function fun3(evt1:Event):void { gotoAndStop(1); }
```